# Scope of variables in JS/nodejs

Tags: javascript

`.content` and `noiseWords` are the arrays which consist of strings. My aim is to remove `noiseWords` from `content`. Both `content` and `noiseWords` are not global variables. Can I access `noiseWords` in the `word()`? Is line 4 correct? If not, then how can I access `noiseWord` inside `word()`?

```
word(content){
// this function remove noiseWords from the Content 
//and then return the content

noiseWords.split(/\s+/).map((w) => 
normalize(w));//line4    

 }

addNoiseWords(noiseWords){
//this function consists noisewords
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In this case, providing the entire code fragment you are trying, with an example of the input data and your desired output would help people provide you with a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I access noiseWords in the word()?

No

> Is the line 4 correct? If not then how can I access noiseWord inside word()? I have mentioned "line 4" in the code.

You need to pass that array as parameter in function `word()`, for example:

```
function word(content, noiseWords){...}
```

or pass an object with those values:

```
function word(obj){
    var {content, noiseWords} = obj;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

or pass an array with those values:

```
function word(array){
    var [content, noiseWords] = array;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: I am not supposed to do so. I can't use word(content,noiseWords). DO you have any other idea?

Comment: function word(obj){
    var {content, noiseWords} = obj;
    .
    .
}  // How can I access noiseWords inside word since noiseWord is not a global varibale? Also I cant change the parameters of word. It has to be word(content).